# Sitemap is not showing hostname on CD server

Tags: sxa, sitemap

This error is little confusing for me. For populating sitemap we are using SXA. Same settings are working on CM server but not on CD server.
`Sitemap.xml` show urls but hostname is missing from there. Here is snapshot.

[image]

`Url => loc` should have host name, but it does not show. It should be something like `https://example.com/searchresults` but it misses the hostname.

Both `CD` and `CM` are on Azure PaaS App service.

Comment: Do you have `targetHostName` set for your site?

Comment: Target hostname is blank

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, `sitemap.xml` host is generated in the following order:

1. If `targetHostName` site property is not empty, it's used.
2. If `hostName` property doesn't contain wildcards (`*`) or multiple hostnames (joined with `|`), it's used.
3. Otherwise request host name is used.

The only scenario which would generate blank host name is when both `targetHostName` and `hostName` are empty. Is that the case?

You should really set `targetHostName` to make sure all your urls for the site are generated with unique host name on your CD server.

Comment: targetHostName is set to blank, hostname is set to wildcard charachter (*). May be targetHomeName is getting used that why it does not show hostname. But same setting are configured on CM. There it work well.

Comment: Which SXA version you use?

Comment: SXA is at 1.5 version

Comment: I assume you use SXA site definition defined on items in Sitecore tree. Can you switch to `web` database and see if your site definition is there and if `hostName` is set to `*` there or it's empty? I don't see any other way how you can get empty hostname in your sitemap.

Comment: Thanks @Marek Musielak, I will just veriy it.